# In nested Fragment,when TabLayout changes new instance of fragment added but RecyclerView not updating

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, custom-adapter, android-nested-fragment

I have a `Fragment` named `HomeFragment`, consisting of a `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` in it. `TabLayout` is populated with data from backend. So each tab item has a name and on changing the tab position, I fetch data from backend and add another fragment, named `SecondFragment` to the `ViewPager`. The `SecondFragment` consists of `RecyclerView` and I am populating it with data from backend. What I need is when tabs changes then an `url` corresponding to it is called and the response data should updated to `RecyclerView` in `SecondFragment` within the `ViewPager`.

What I have did so far is as following:

Populating `TabLayout`:

```
mViewPager= (ViewPager)rootview.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
mTabLayout= (TabLayout)rootview.findViewById(R.id.tabs);


HomeModel model;
planList = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
try {
    jsonArray = resultData.getJSONArray("details");
    editor.putString("tab",jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("name"));
    editor.commit();
    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
        jsonObject2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        model = new HomeModel();
        model.setCatid(jsonObject2.getString("id"));
        model.setImage(jsonObject2.getString("image"));
        model.setName(jsonObject2.getString("name"));
        planList.add(model);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager,jsonObject2.getString("name"));
    }
    setAdapter();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
private void setAdapter() {
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);  
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager mViewPager,String name) {
    adapter.addFragment(new SecondFragment(), name);
}
```

`TabsSelectListener`:

```
mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(
    new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager) {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            super.onTabSelected(tab);
            numTab = tab.getPosition();
            HomeModel browsePlan = planList.get(numTab);
            editor.putString("tab", browsePlan.getName()).apply();
        }
    });
```

In my `SecondFragment` I am `just` populating data from to `Recyclerview` using a custom adapter class:

`SecondFragment` code snippet:

```
planList = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    jsonArray = resultData.getJSONArray("products");
    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
        jsonObject2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        model = new Spaceship();
        model.setName(jsonObject2.getString("package_name"));
        model.setImage(jsonObject2.getString("images"));
        planList.add(model);
    }
    setAdapter();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

adding to adapter:

```
private void setAdapter() {
    adapter = new RecyclerHomeAdapter(getContext(), planList);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Custom Adapter class

```
public class RecyclerHomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerHomeAdapter.MyHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Spaceship> spaceships;
    private Context c;

    public RecyclerHomeAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Spaceship> spaceships) {
        this.spaceships = spaceships;
        this.c = c;
    }
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.home_package,parent,false);
        return new MyHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
        Spaceship s=spaceships.get(position);

        holder.nameTxt.setText(s.getName());

        Glide.with(c).load(s.getImage())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .fitCenter()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_image)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(holder.img);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return spaceships.size();
    }

    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView nameTxt;
        ImageView img;

        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nameTxt= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
            img= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.spacecraftImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Adding tabs, showing `SecondFragment` inside `ViewPager` with populated `RecyclerView` are working.
My problem is when changing tabs. I have logged and found that I am getting correct data inside `SecondFragment` on changing each tabs, but that data not updating to `RecyclerView`. When tabs changes `RecyclerView` shows previous data.

How can I make it works fine on tabs change, i.e update `RecyclerVierw` with data I am getting on adding each instance of `SecondFragment` to `ViewPager`?

All responses are appreciated.

Adding some screenshots for identifying my issue.
I have multiple tabs,lotto,cricket,football etc.. as shown in the image.
[image]

When each tab is selected I am fetching data from backend and populate it to a RecyclerView in anotherFragment "SecondFragment", which is added to the ViewPager below the TabLayout, as shown in the image.

But when i swipe to next fragment tab changes to cricket, and data from backend corresponding to "cricket" is fetched in the "SecondFragment", but it not updating the `RecyclerView`, as shown in the second image.
[image]

And again, on swipe to the next tab "football", data corresponding to "cricket" is showing and so on as shown in image 3, and then swiping back to first tab, it shows data corresponding to any other tab.
I don't know why its not get updated .

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, which part of code is for the new data that you aren't seeing in your view? Is that the planList? Can you give example of what you see and what you expect to see maybe?

Comment: Something is missing here. You have `HomeFragment` and inside it `ViewPager` which contains `SecondFragment` and what is used as `FirstFragment` or whatever you call it? In `TabPagerAdapter` count is basically `3` (starting from 0) but you have just one `fragment`?

Comment: In my SecondFragment,  I am adding data models to ArrayList named planList, and then the planList is send to customAdapter class. I check the values adding to planList on each tab change and found its coreect.But the newly added values to planList is not updating to RecyclerView instead it shows previous tabs values. I will edit my question to add the custom adapter class too

Comment: @Yupi, sorry, actually that part doesn't have any role, i removed it.

Comment: Your question is still confusing and approach as well. Why you just didn't create two `fragments` and assign them to `ViewPager` using `adapter`? In each you can than have `recyclerview` and implement logic to download desired data from internet.

Comment: @yupi, fragment named SecondFragment is inside HomeFragment. What i need is, when tabs in homefragment changes an API corresponding to that tab is called and that response data should populate the RecyclerView in the SecondFragment. The number of tabs in HomeFragment changes always, so i can't use multiple fragment, i want to use singe fragment, SecondFragment for all tabs to show in ViewPager.

Comment: @Yupi, I have added screenshots for better analysis of the issue.

Comment: @visakhr do you have somewhere code stored like Bitbucket or Github, where is possible to take a look on whole code?

Comment: No, actually i have added all codes in the question itself